# Бот флудит после включения pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Суть проблемы в следующем: если отправлять команды боту в телеграмме, пока он выключен, то при включении он начинает сразу отвечать на все, введенные, пока он был выключен, команды. Есть ли какая-то возможность отключить это? Использую pyTelegramBotApi

Comment: Могу предложить неочивидное решение - не отвечать на сообщение если оно прислано спустя 15 мин например. Достаньте датувремя из запроса и сравните с текущей...

Comment: или вычитать очередь перед стартом

Comment: Может у вас там цикл while стоит лишний,или же вы используете неправильно плагин клавиатуры

Comment: это нормальное поведение поллинга, не помню как на хуках, но вроде они не скапливаются

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте вот эту строку в код:

```
bot.skip_pending = True
```

То есть у вас должно получится:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.skip_pending = True
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Удачи!

Comment: Не нужно дублировать ответ под разными вопросами, вместо этого стоит поставить тревогу о дубликате вопросов

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы убрать все апдейты нужно делать так.
PS. Даже если вы не юзаете вебхуки

```
bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Без `bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)` и при `bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)` бот будет обрабатывать последний апдейт для каждого чата.